# NetBeans PHP app not running

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xampp

This is my problem:
- I downloaded and installed XAMPP;
- I changed the listen port from 80 to 100 (to not interfere with Skype);
- in browser i typed: localhost:127.0.0.1:100
WAMPP page appears. So far so good. I opened NetBeans and tried to run a PHP application and I got Error 404.

Apache service is running (at least XAMPP reports soand the Apache icon is showing). 
I use Win 7 on laptop, 64 b.

So, what can I do to successfully run the application.

Tank you,

Eugen

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
Listen 81
```

in `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` ?

Or do you have the vhosts properly configured?

```
<VirtualHost *:100>
....
```

Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in `httpd.conf`?

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: I have Listen 100   (I changed from 80 to 100)

Comment: does the application have a virtual host? where is it hosted? inside xampp/htdocs?

Comment: If by application you mean the php app, then I tell you is TodoList from netbeans samples. I saved the files in in xampp/htdocs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to check mod_rewrite.

Comment: Please check my answer. Should be in httpd.conf

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed it. Yes, I have LoadModule rewrite_module ..... and is not commented.

Comment: I guess I solved the problem: I had the project files in C:\xampp\htdocs\. I moved them in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\, I changed accordingly the path for index.php and now all the samples in NetBeans work. Thank you for your help; it was really very useful.